# How to load react-app on another computer

Tags: reactjs

I didn't think this would be very hard to find a solution for but I really can't find anything on google. How do I share my react-app with a co-worker. I would assume you just give them everything except for the node_modules since that's the bulk of the project and then somehow install the packages from their machine using 'npm install' or something along those lines? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the approach that you suggested in your question? Providing all files/directories other than node_modules and then doing `npm install`. It just might work. There are also source control solutions such as Github and Bitbucket that could allow you to share/collaborate the code with others. Bitbucket has free, private repositories if it needs to be kept private. It would be just about excluding certain files/directories such as node_modules using a .gitignore file.

Comment: @alexanderStaroselsky I feel like my idea is close to what it is, but I am surprised there is nothing online to support this notion. My company has a repository (svn) so I assume I should just use that, but I was hoping there was some fast way to do this, I don't know.

Comment: What you suggested is an absolutely valid manual way to achieve the sharing. I just think there may not be many resources on this as it's usually encouraged to utilize git/tfs/svn/etc to share/collaborate the code in a more structured fashion.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to just copy the project and then run 'npm install' on the other computer.